# l.s.c. on compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X$ be a real Banach space. Consider a function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ is l.s.c. . Let $D$ be a compact subset of X. I want to show that $f$ is bounded from below on $D$.

Suppose it's not. That means that there exists a sequance $(x_n)\subset D$ such that $$f(x_{n})\to-\infty.$$ Since $D$ is compact, I can extract a  subsequance $(x_{n_k})$ from $(x_n)$ convergent to some $x_0$. Now I observe that $$-\infty<f(x_0)\le \liminf_{k\to \infty}f(x_{n_k})\le\lim_{k\to \infty}f(x_{n_k})\to-\infty$$ 
which leads to a contradiction. My question is: *how do we know that $\lim_{k\to \infty}f(x_{n_k})\to-\infty$?*

My question is motivated by the following argument: we do not know if the sequance $(x_{n})$ is convergent to any point in $D$. We only know that the sequance $f(x_{n})$ tends to $-\infty$. So how do we deduce that $\lim_{k\to \infty}f(x_{n_k})\to-\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a sequence converges, if and only if, every subsequence converges to the same limit. So if we consider $\{f(x_n)\}$ as a sequence of numbers in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]$ we see that by choice $f(x_n)\to -\infty$. In particular, since $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ is a subsequence of $\{f(x_n)\}$ we have that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n_k})=-\infty$ as well.

In your question you mention that we don't know that the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent to any point in $D$, but this is not important since we are only looking at the *values* of the $f$ along the subsequence. In particular, the subsequential limit only depends on the limit of the $\mathbb{R}$-valued sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$.